# Proper way to obtain ACTION_SCROLL MotionEvent

Tags: android, motionevent

I have a task to inject programmatically mouse scroll event. Scroll could be both horizontal and vertical. To achieve this I decided to use MotionEvent with ACTION_SCROLL. But it is unclear for me how to initialize this event type. How scroll offset in the AXIS_VSCROLL and AXIS_HSCROLL should be defined?

I tried to log the actual Scroll MotionEvent from USB mouse:

```
MotionEvent DownTime 91208223
MotionEvent EventTime 91221679
MotionEvent Action 8
MotionEvent PointerCount 1

MotionEvent.PointerCoords x 98.14349
MotionEvent.PointerCoords y 23.289246
MotionEvent.PointerCoords size 0.0
MotionEvent.PointerCoords pressure 0.0
MotionEvent.PointerCoords orientation 0.0
MotionEvent.PointerCoords toolMajor 0.0
MotionEvent.PointerCoords toolMinor 0.0
MotionEvent.PointerCoords toolMinor 0.0
MotionEvent.PointerCoords touchMajor 0.0
MotionEvent.PointerCoords AXIS_HSCROLL 0.0
MotionEvent.PointerCoords AXIS_VSCROLL -1.0

MotionEvent.PointerProperties id 0
MotionEvent.PointerProperties toolType 3

MotionEvent MetaState 0
MotionEvent ButtonState 0
MotionEvent XPrecision 1.0
MotionEvent YPrecision 1.0
MotionEvent DeviceId 8
MotionEvent EdgeFlags 0
MotionEvent Source 8194
MotionEvent Flags 2
```

and basing on those logs tried to obtain own event:

```
    MotionEvent.PointerCoords coord = new MotionEvent.PointerCoords();
    coord.x = 500f;
    coord.y = 500f;
    coord.setAxisValue(MotionEvent.AXIS_VSCROLL, 1f);
    MotionEvent.PointerCoords[] coords = { coord };

    MotionEvent.PointerProperties properties = new MotionEvent.PointerProperties();
    properties.toolType = 3;
    MotionEvent.PointerProperties[] prop = { properties };

    MotionEvent mouseEvent = MotionEvent.obtain(downTime, downTime + 100,
            MotionEvent.ACTION_SCROLL, 1, prop, coords, 0, 0, 1f, 1f,
            8, 0, 8194, 0);
```

obtain() method parameters:

```
    MotionEvent obtain (
        long downTime,
        long eventTime,
        int action,
        int pointerCount,
        PointerProperties[] pointerProperties,
        PointerCoords[] pointerCoords,
        int metaState,
        int buttonState,
        float xPrecision,
        float yPrecision,
        int deviceId,
        int edgeFlags,
        int source,
        int flags
    )
```

Comment: just wild guess: use `MotionEvent.PointerCoords` and pass it to `MotionEvent#obtain()` method?

Comment: @pskink, sounds like possible solution. But i didn't get positive results.

Comment: maybe `PointerCoords` are not correctly initialized? tried to call `MotionEvent#getPointerCoords` to see the typical values? also `3` is mouse? and why `downTime + 100` ?

Comment: Actually trouble was in pointerProperties.id, by default it was set to -1

Comment: ahh, good to know, thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks to directional questions from @pskink, the following event was constructed:

```
    MotionEvent.PointerCoords coord = new MotionEvent.PointerCoords();
    coord.x = x;
    coord.y = y;
    coord.setAxisValue(MotionEvent.AXIS_VSCROLL, 1f);
    MotionEvent.PointerCoords[] coords = { coord };

    MotionEvent.PointerProperties properties = new MotionEvent.PointerProperties();
    properties.id = 0;
    MotionEvent.PointerProperties[] prop = { properties };

    MotionEvent scrollEvent = MotionEvent.obtain(
    SystemClock.uptimeMillis(), SystemClock.uptimeMillis(), MotionEvent.ACTION_SCROLL,
    1, prop, coords, 0, 0, 1f, 1f, 0, 0, SOURCE_CLASS_POINTER, 0);

    dispatchEvent(scrollEvent);
```

Comment: Thank you! `coord.setAxisValue()` did the trick!